# When i click on Button next that goto next page how to write a code on Button that go to next page

Tags: asp.net

When i click on Button next that goto next page how to write a code on Button that go to next page

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="DodgerBlue"
                Text="Next" />
```

Comment: haven't you tried googling this first.

Answer (score 0):

Add onclick event to button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="DodgerBlue"
                Text="Next" OnClick="btnNext_Click"/>
```

In code behind

```
 protected void btnNext_Click(object sender,Event args e)
    {
    Response.Redirect("newPageUrl.aspx");
    }
```

You can also do this using JavaScript , no need of code in code behind

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="DodgerBlue"
                    Text="Next OnClick="document.location.href='newPageUrl.aspx';"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="DodgerBlue"
                Text="Next"  OnClick="btnNext_click"/>
```

in the code behind

```
protected void btnNext_click(objecter sender,Event args e)
{
Response.Redirect("yourUrl", True);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!!

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="DodgerBlue"
                    Text="Next OnClientClick="window.location.href='newPageUrl.aspx';"/>
```